# Ruby shoes using spawn

Tags: ruby, spawn, shoes

I am trying to use *Process.spawn* in my shoes app

I managed to run this command:

```
pid = Process.spawn("calc")
```

but I couldn't run this one from shoes:

```
pid = Process.spawn("calc",[:out, :err]=>["log", 'w'])
```

any suggestions ?

both command works on Ruby interpreter

This is the code:

```
@run.click {
    log_file = "C:/A/B/text.txt"
    spawn("calc", [:out, :err]=>[log_file, 'w'])
    alert("finished")
}
```

This is the error:

```
Wrong exec redirect
test.rb 163:in 'spawn'
test.rb 163:in 'block (2 levels) in <main>'
:0:in 'call'
```

Comment: You "couldn't run" that command?  What happens?

Comment: It is part of a button.click block, it just exit from the block.I am still trying to learn how to debug shoes program

Comment: It always helps to post as much of the code as you can, so someone can reproduce it and possibly help out.  Such as this button click block, or even more.

Comment: Added some more information.

Comment: If you call `open(log_file)` as a test, does it succeed?  I don't know much about using Windows paths in Ruby.  You could try making `log_file` a relative path like `test.txt` and see if it improves/changes things.